# Does `git reset` switch to another branch as the current branch?

Tags: git

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset says:

> git-reset - Reset current HEAD to the specified state

1. `HEAD` points to (the most recent commit, i.e. the tip of) the current branch. It can be changed to point to a
   different branch, without modifying any branch, by `git checkout`.

   In the manpage of `git reset`, the use of `HEAD` in "reset current
   HEAD to the specified state" seems to me that `git reset` switch to
   another branch as the current branch, similarly to `git checkout`.
2. But from what I head `git reset` actually changes which commit is
   the most recent commit on the current branch. If that is the case,
   then is it more clear if the manpage of `git reset` avoid mentioning `HEAD`? For
   example should the manpage of `git reset` say something like "move
   the tip of the current branch to a previous commit on the same
   branch, shortening the current branch" instead of "reset current
   HEAD to the specified state"?

Which is correct, my understanding of the wording in manpage literally, or what I heard?

Comment: Head is a commit, not a branch. It's the head of whatever branch you're on. "Should" it say that, explicitly? *shrug* Not a question for SO.

Comment: `git reset` can take `--soft`, `--mixed`, or `--hard` as parameters.  This is a broad question.

Comment: I prefer going with man page. Sometimes it is hard to comprehend all options provided by a git command in one go. Going over the description for each command variation (may be multiple times) and trying few examples would reveal the real meaning of man page summary. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a bunch of issues with the Git documentation, but StackOverflow isn't the right place to discuss how to fix the Git documentation. :-)

Comment: @torek  I am not trying to change the manpage. I just want clarification for correct understanding.

Comment: You might want to fiddle with your question-wording, then. Item 2 sounds like it suggests that the documentation should say Y, not X, i.e., that the documentation is buggy. (Which I think it is, in a very broad sense, but again, that's out of scope for SO)

Answer (score 5):

#### Short

> ... "move the tip of the current branch to a previous commit on the same branch, shortening the current branch" ...

This *is* one of the ways `git reset` can be used.  However, it can also *lengthen* the current branch, or move it entirely somewhere else, or do neither.  If `HEAD` is attached (the usual case), the effect on the name-as-pointer is more of a "go to":

```
            F   <-- a
           /
       D--E   <-- b (HEAD)
      /
...--C--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

Since `HEAD` is attached to the name `b`, `git reset` to some arbitrary commit, such as `H` or `I`, will *move* `b` so that it points to that commit.  If you pick `C` or `D`, that could be viewed as "shorten the current branch" (in which case the remaining commits are now only on branch `a`).  If you pick `F`, however, so that `b` and `a` both point to `F`, that could be viewed as "lengthen the current branch".  If you pick commit `J`, so that `b` and `develop` both point to`J`, it's hard to call that shortening *or* lengthening.

#### Long

The `git reset` command is very complicated, because—like a number of other Git commands—it does some things that aren't necessarily related to each other.  For instance, `git reset -p file` acts as a sort of inverse of `git add -p file`, and in fact, the two operations (add and reset with -p) are both implemented by a different *internal* Git command written in Perl, rather than by the C-coded programs named `git-reset` and `git-add`.<sup>1</sup>

However, there are three "main mode" resets, all of which share a common set of things that they do.  These are the ones that you get with `git reset --soft`, `git reset --mixed`, and `git reset --hard`, none of which allow path name specifiers, but all of which allow a commit-specifier:

```
git reset --soft a234567
git reset --mixed cafedad
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

for instance.

What these do is:

1. Resolve the commit-specifier to a commit hash ID, a la `git rev-parse`.  A short hash like `a234567` or `cafedad` gets looked up in the hash-ID database and turned into the full hash ID.  A name like `master` or `v2.3` gets looked up in the name-to-hash-ID database, then converted to a commit hash if necessary.  A relative name like `HEAD~3` directs Git to resolve the first part, then apply the relation operator, so `HEAD~3` first looks up the hash ID for `HEAD`, then counts back three first-parents in the commit graph.

   This step can fail, either because the hash ID is invalid, or because it cannot be resolved to a commit (is the hash ID of a tree or blob).  In that case, `git reset` stops with an error message.

   You can omit the commit specifier, in which case the commit specifier is read from the current value of `HEAD`.  That is, if `HEAD` is attached to some branch name—if you're on `master` or `develop`, for instance—Git will read the hash ID from that branch name.  If `HEAD` is detached, it already contains a raw hash ID, so Git will read the hash ID out of `HEAD`.
2. Now that `git reset` has the hash ID, it writes that hash ID into or through `HEAD`.<sup>2</sup>  That is, if `HEAD` is attached to a branch name, Git will store the new hash ID into that branch name.  If `HEAD` is detached, Git will write the newly-selected hash ID into `HEAD`.

   Note that if you specified `HEAD` in step 1, or did not specify anything in step 1, this writes the current value read *from* `HEAD` back into-or-through `HEAD`, which means nothing changes.  However, if you *did* specify some other commit, then at this point either `HEAD` itself changes (the detached-HEAD case), or the target of `HEAD` changes (the attached-HEAD case).
3. If you used `--soft`, `git reset` is now finished.

   Otherwise—for `--mixed` or `--hard`—`git reset` now resets the index, making its contents match the commit identified by `HEAD`.
4. If you used `--mixed`, `git reset` is now finished.

   Otherwise—i.e., for `git reset --hard` only—`git reset` now resets the work-tree, making its contents match the index that was just reset in step 3.

(Steps 3 and/or 4 can also fail.  If step 3 fails, Git can restore `HEAD` and the index to the way they were before `git reset` even started, because Git updates these two entities by creating new ones and then using an atomic operation to swap the updates into the underlying file system.  If step 4 fails, however, you'll likely be left with a mess.)

---

<sup>1</sup>When you run `git xyz`, Git pushes an internal `git-core` directory into `$PATH`.  (The description here is slightly sh / bash-centric, but the algorithm is the same even on Windows.)  Run `git --exec-path` to see where this `git-core` directory lives in your installation.  Look in that directory and you'll find programs named `git-add`, `git-commit`, `git-rebase`, `git-reset`, and so on.  So the way `git xyz` works is that Git sets up some context, inserts this "core" directory at the front of `$PATH`, and then invokes `git-xyz`.  If that file exists in `git-core`, that's the one that runs now.  If not, any *other* file named `git-xyz` that is anywhere in your `$PATH` will run.  So you can write your own program, build it into an executable named `git-xyz`, and run it with `git xyz`, as long as there is no `git-xyz` in this git-core directory.

<sup>2</sup>The name `HEAD` is very special in Git.  It's literally hard-coded in various source files, and back in the ancient past of Git, it was stored as a symbolic link.  This method does not work on Windows so at some point, the name got a little bit less special: it's now possible for *any* reference to be what Git calls a *symbolic reference*.  A symbolic reference is a reference that is resolved by reading some other reference.  The command `git symbolic-ref` is the external interface for reading and writing such references.

While any reference can be made symbolic now, `HEAD` is still precious to Git: if the file is missing, Git will claim that a repository is no longer a repository.  Since this is one of the most active files *in* a repository, if your system crashes while you're doing some Git command, sometimes the file goes missing.  In that case, you can often recover everything just by manually creating the missing `HEAD` file.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1, `HEAD` -> Branch Foo -> Commit A.

Case 2, `HEAD` -> Commit A.

In Case 1, `HEAD` points at a branch and the branch points at a commit. `git branch` returns `* Foo`. In Case 2, it's detached HEAD state. `HEAD` directly points at a commit. `git branch` returns `HEAD detached at xxxxxxx` or `(no branch)`.

In Case 1, `git reset` makes `Foo` point at a specific commit. As `HEAD` points at `Foo`, it will indirectly point at the commit too.

In Case 2, `git reset` makes `HEAD` point at a specific commit. No branch is involved.